# How android watch gets the internet from android device?

Tags: android, wear-os

Currently i am working on stock app in wear device and it gets the json data from the API and tested in wear emulator but question is that in actual wear device how to get json data from API....

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Comment: Android Wear devices are just an extension of the smartphone they are connected to. They are not supposed to have a direct Internet connection. Instead any information you need on the watch has to be fetched on the smartphone and then transfered to the watch with the Wear API which is part of Google Play Services.

Comment: Having said that there are Android Wear devices that have a modem installed and can use a sim just like a smartphone to connect to the Internet directly - however that is not the norm and not how Android Wear devices are supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that wearables haven't changed significantly in the last 6-12 months, the answer is Bluetooth and/or NFC, depending on the specific phone and device. The phone and device are paired when you setup the device.

So, in your scenario it is actually a background service on the phone that will obtain the JSON data and send a message to the device to launch whatever action you specify.

Comment: You mean to say that, We need to pass the data first wear to android device and then API will be called ??   Is that possible that without passing string from wear to device and Can we call API directly from wear ? @BrianDriscoll